# pages always 100% height and 100%width

Tags: css

How is it possible to build a one page website with different pages with each page that has a 100% width and 100% height? 
My first solution would be a fixed value but I want it to scale to the size of the screen. So that each page has the size of the screen. 
Note that it has to be a "one page" so the pages will be underneath each other.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking if it's possible? Yes, it is. But what do you *really* want to know?

Comment: How can `one page` be 100% of browser window height?

Comment: You want a one page multi-page site? And your concern is with the height and width?

Comment: I find it hard to explain. But I want a one page design website. But which has 4 pages underneath eachother. Like a list or something. But I want each page to fit the screen perfectly. I dont want to see all the 4 pages when I am on a 27" screen for instance. No, I still want to 1 full page and I have to scroll down to see the other one. So it needs to be responsive-ish. So it shoudnt matter on which screensize I look at it. Sorry for the vague question and answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you need:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #parent { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
    #parent div { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
    #parent div:nth-child(1) { background: red; }
    #parent div:nth-child(2) { background: green; }
    #parent div:nth-child(3) { background: blue; }
    #parent div:nth-child(4) { background: orange; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The divs inside the #parent all have a height of 100%. Even if you resize the screen.
Tested it on Chrome, IE and Firefox.

Comment: This is exacly what I was looking for! Thank you very much sir!

Comment: No problem :) could you mark it as accepted answer by clicking the "check" sign? Would help out others with the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends how you want to build it and resize it. Is it responsive? If so, make sure you use then a framework that supports it.

Also, start off as following in your CSS

```
body, html              {height: 100%;width: 100%;}
```

This will always fill your screen for 100% with the body. Now for your secondairy question. You want to fill each page? Cause you lost me there. Content is varriable, thus cant always fit on a 100% height and width (think of smartphones, you have to scroll sometimes, due to the limited width and height in pixels from a smartphone)

I suggest your pages should be sections, and place them in my body tag. Each section is then a different element and you can call them off your menu (i asume you want to scroll then down in your menu) so simply giving them an ID and the page will jump to it with the help of JQuery or JavaScript.

Do a codecheck on this page to see what I mean: http://www.jellyfishwebdesign.nl/Joost/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Give `height:100%` to **html,body** & your **page container**.

Answer (score 0):

I think this CSS solution is enough..

```
<body>
  <section id="one">
  </section>
  <section id="two">
  </section>
  <section id="three">
  </section>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
html,body {
   height:100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}

#one {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}

#two {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}

#three {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
```